# Terraform Interpolation in outputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform

I create an AWS RDS instance with different KMS CMKs depending on whether or not the environment is Production or Non-Production. So I have two resources that use the terraform count if:

```
count = "${var.bluegreen == "nonprod" ? 1 : 0}"
```

This spins up an RDS instance with different KMS keys with different addresses. I need to capture that endpoint (which I do with terraform show after the build finishes) so why doesn't this work in Terraform?

```
output "rds_endpoint" {
    value = "${var.bluegreen == "nonprod" ? aws_db_instance.rds_nonprod.address : aws_db_instance.rds_prod.address}"
}
```

Comment: I know how to workaround this - kms_key_id = "${var.bluegreen == "nonprod" ? "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:1234567890:key/foo" : "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:1234567890:key/bar"}" in a single aws_db_instance resource reducing the aws_db_instance resource to one (from two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an error to access attributes of a resource that has `count = 0`, and unfortunately Terraform currently checks both "sides" of a conditional during its check step, so expressions like this can fail. Along with this, there is a current behavior that errors in outputs are not explicitly shown since outputs can get populated when the state isn't yet complete (e.g. as a result of using `-target`). These annoyances all sum up to a lot of confusion in this case.

Instead of using a conditional expression in this case, it works better to use "splat expressions", which evaluate to an empty list in the case where `count = 0`. This would looks something like the following:

```
output "rds_endpoint" {
    value = "${element(concat(aws_db_instance.rds_nonprod.*.address, aws_db_instance.rds_prod.*.address), 0)}"
}
```

This takes the first element of a list created by concatenating together all of the nonprod addresses and all of the prod addresses. Due to how you've configured `count` on these resource blocks, the resulting list will only ever have one element and so it will just take that element.

In general, to debug issues with outputs it can be helpful to evaluate the expressions in `terraform console`, or somewhere else in a config, to bypass the limitation that errors are silently ignored on outputs.

Comment: Great answer, I hadn't considered "splat expressions". From your answer can I assume that another method is available to the way I have used count? I ask as I have seen unexpected behaviour from this method - for example an aws security group rule resource being destroyed on a second run when the count comparison should be the same (bluegreen still equals nonprod).

Comment: Indeed there are some challenges with the `element` function where if you pass it anything that is `<computed>` -- even in part -- then its result is computed, because Terraform's core treats all functions conservatively. In this case I didn't expect problems since it looked more like a "one or the other" sort of situation, but this gets tricky if you are creating a bunch of correlated resources with `count.index` connecting between them. As long as `bluegreen` stays set to `nonprod` here things should be stable.